# Is there a simpler way to read multiple sheets of an excel workbook into a single pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I need to read in a list of SKUs for three different years (2019, 2020, and 2021), all of which exist in an Excel workbook, each with a worksheet labeled for the year. I want to read in all three worksheets into a single dataframe, and create a column for the appropriate year for which a SKU belongs.

The way I did it is very manual (see below). Is there a more efficient way to code this?

```
'''
Read in the yearly SKU worksheets
'''
df2019= pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name='2019', index_col=None, header=0)
df2019['Year'] = '2019'

df2020= pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name='2020', index_col=None, header=0)
df2020['Year'] = '2020'

df2021= pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name='2021', index_col=None, header=0)
df2021['Year'] = '2021'

df_all=pd.concat([df2019, df2020, df2021])

df_all.head(9)
```

My output is as follows:
[image: Output]

Comment: Pass a list to `sheet_name`.

Comment: @sj95126 I know.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`pandas.read_excel`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) and make `sheet_name=None` to return a dict of dataframes when the keys are the sheets names.

Try this :

```
dict_df_all = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name=None, index_col=None, header=0)

for k, v in dict_df_all.items():
    v['Year'] = k
    
df_all = pd.concat(dict_df_all, ignore_index=True)
```